# Let $X$ be a infinite dimesional normed space, $M$, $N$ be subspaces with $ M \subseteq N$. Show $\dim X/N \leq \dim X/M$

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis

Let $X$ be a infinite dimesional normed space. Let $M$, $N$ be subspaces such that $ M \subseteq N$. How can we show $$\dim X/N \leq \dim X/M$$?

I think this is intuitively clear and in the case $X$ is a finite dim'l, we can actually prove by noting $\dim M \leq \dim N$.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the map $\Phi : X/M\to X/N$, defined by $\Phi(x+M) := x+N$. This definition makes sense since if $x+M = y+M$, then $x-y\in M\subset N$ and thus $x+N = y+N$. The map $\Phi$ is obviously linear and surjective. Hence, if $X/M$ is finite-dimensional, then so is $X/N$ and, in this case, $\dim(X/M) = \dim\operatorname{ran}\Phi + \dim\ker\Phi\ge\dim\operatorname{ran}\Phi = \dim(X/N)$.

Since you asked for cardinalities: The space $N/M$ is a subspace of $X/M$, so we can consider the space $\tfrac{X/M}{N/M}$ and the map $\psi : \tfrac{X/M}{N/M}\to X/N$, defined by $\psi((x+M) + N/M) := x+N$. This map is easily seen to be bijective. So, if $\{x_i + M: i\in I\}$ is a basis for $X/M$, then $\{(x_i+M) + N/M : i\in I\}$ spans $\tfrac{X/M}{N/M}$. Therefore, there exists $J\subset I$ such that $\{(x_i+M) + N/M : i\in J\}$ is a basis for $\tfrac{X/M}{N/M}$. Applying $\psi$ we find that $\{x_i+N : i\in J\}$ is a basis for $X/N$. Hence, $\dim X/N = |J|\le |I| = \dim X/M$.

Comment: Is there any result when $X/M$ is not finite dimensional? I guess there should be some cardinality involved..

Comment: I added a paragraph concerning this question.

Comment: So Third isomorphism theorem gives the answer. Thank you.